# Logging the request protocol in nginx?

Tags: nginx

I was surprised to find that I couldn't find any information on logging the request protocol in an nginx access log. I usually share a server block for both HTTP (80) and HTTPS (443) traffic, and use a combined access log for both. I'd like to indicate in each line in the access log if the request was over HTTP or HTTPS.

Is this possible, or do I need to use a separate server block for HTTPS and specify a separate access log for SSL?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It's a bit hidden in the docs, but you can use any of the common variables. This includes `$scheme`.

Comment: What file/section did you add it to, to get the output in the syslog?

Comment: I found it, but its always `http`! Something to do with the SSL ending at our ELB.

Comment: Thank you and thank SO!  This was hard to track down.

Answer (score -4):

You can combine server blocks like:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 default_server ssl;

    # other directives
}
```

[> nginx http/https config docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html#single_http_https_server)

For customizing the log file output you can use the "log_format" directive to define your own access log setup.

[> nginx access_log docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_log_module.html)

Comment: I know I can combine those, I'm asking if I can somehow log the request protocol. I don't see that in the docs, but feel like it would be a common thing people do?